# Superfish vertical menu with active page

Tags: javascript, jquery, superfish

I am integrating super fish as a vertical menu. I would like the current page highlighted and it's submenu expanded via javascript. This looks like what I am looking for functionally http://jsfiddle.net/Zx2EU/3/, but I'm trying to append the active/current state via javascript, checking the page URL vs. the href. I found this code, but cannot implement it correctly:

```
var path = window.location.pathname.split('/');
path = path[path.length-1];
if (path !== undefined) {
  $("ul.sf-menu")
    .find("a[href$='" + path + "']") // gets all links that match the href
    .parents('li')  // gets all list items that are ancestors of the     link
    .children('a')  // walks down one level from all selected li's
    .addClass('current');
}
```

I started a jsfiddle, but I don't have access to https, so I can't link the external js and css: https://jsfiddle.net/7w27a5cc/

In this case, I am testing it with the navbar_3.html link in the second submenu to no avail.

Many thanks--

Comment: Seems to work fine here https://jsfiddle.net/7w27a5cc/2/ with hard coded path

Comment: Thanks--it does, but I am trying to set it up in such a way that it could parse the URL via js and match the URL with the href so it automatically sets it up without hardcoding it. Is that possible?

Comment: sure it is. Just need to debug the values in your url parsing to make sure they are what you expect them to be